# How to ignore placeholder expressions for Flyway?

Tags: java, mysql, flyway

I am using flyway version 2.3, I have an sql patch which inserts a varchar into a table having character sequence that Flyway treats as placeholders. I want to flyway to ignore placeholders and run the script as is.

The script file is

`insert into test_data (value) values ("${Email}");`

And the Java code is

```
package foobar;

import com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        // Create the Flyway instance
        Flyway flyway = new Flyway();

        // Point it to the database
        flyway.setDataSource("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/flywaytest", "alpha", "beta");

        // Start the migration
        flyway.migrate();
    }
}
```

Comment: See similar: [Disabling Flyway Placeholder Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26868233/642706)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the value of the placeholder [suffix](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/placeholderSuffix) or [prefix](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/placeholderPrefix) to a different value and you should be OK.

Answer (score 18):

This can be done by splitting $ and { in the expression:

```
insert into test_data (value) values ('$' || '{Email}')
```

Comment: Now that's the hack I like to see!

Answer (score 5):

In my MySQL migration script this worked:

I just escaped the first `{` characters, like this:

```
'...<p>\nProgram name: $\{programName}<br />\nStart of studies: $\{startOfStudies}<br />\n($\{semesterNote})\n</p>...'
```

This way flyway didn't recognize them as placeholders, and the string finally stored doesn't contain the escape character.

```
...<p>
Program name: ${programName}<br />
Start of studies: ${startOfStudies}<br />
(${semesterNote})
</p>...
```

Answer (score 3):

try this properties:

```java
        final var flyway = Flyway.configure()
                .dataSource(DataSourceProvider.getInstanceDataSource())
                .locations("path")
                .outOfOrder(true)
                .validateOnMigrate(false)
                .placeholderReplacement(false)
                .load();
```

Answer (score 2):

**I had exactly the same problem, but the accepted answer didn't fit my requirements**. So I solved the problem in another way and post this answer hoping that it'll be useful to other people coming here from Google search.

If you cannot change the placeholder suffix and prefix, you can trick Flyway into believing there are no placeholders by using an expression. E.g.:

```
INSERT INTO test_data(value) VALUES (REPLACE("#{Email}", "#{", "${"));
```

This is useful if you've already used placeholders in lots of previous migrations. (If you **just** change placeholder suffix and prefix, you'll have to change them in previous migration scripts, too. But then the migration script checksums won't match, Flyway will rightfully complain, and you'll have to change checksums in the `schema_version` table by calling `Flyway#repair()` or manually altering the table.)

Answer (score 1):

In 2021, the simple answer is to set the `placeholderReplacement` boolean to false:

```
flyway -placeholderReplacement="false"
```

The configuration parameter `placeholderReplacement` determines whether placeholders should be replaced.

Reference: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/placeholderReplacement

Answer (score 0):

Just add a property to your `bootstrap.properties` (or whatever you use)

```
flyway.placeholder-replacement = false
```