# Disabling Flyway Placeholder Validation

Tags: flyway

So what I understood after upgrading my flyway version because of some requirements is that flyway-core-2.2 introduced some validation for Flyway placeholders.

Now, the convention of placeholder syntax is ${name} uniform across most libraries. In our migration scripts, we are inserting a string in a mysql table column called stretchySql and that string holds some placeholder elements of our own which is meant to be interpreted at runtime by the application layer.

`` UPDATE `stretchy_parameter` SET `parameter_sql`='select  r.id as report_id from stretchy_report r where r.report_category = \'${reportCategory}\' ``

I don't want flyway to interpret something embedded in a string as its own placeholder and throw an error. So basically, is there some way to switch off flyway placeholder validation(since we don't use it) without reverting back to an older version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you can't disable it, you can set the placeholder prefix or suffix to something that will never match. This will effectively achieve the same thing.

http://flywaydb.org/documentation/api/javadoc/org/flywaydb/core/Flyway.html#setPlaceholderPrefix(java.lang.String)

Comment: Can you point me towards some documentation on how to change the prefix or suffix of flyway placeholders?

Comment: http://flywaydb.org/documentation/api/javadoc/org/flywaydb/core/Flyway.html#setPlaceholderPrefix(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 9):

As of Flyway 3.2.1 (not sure when it was introduced) there is a new boolean setting called `flyway.placeholderReplacement`, which defaults to true, and you can use that to effectively disable the feature. On the API it can be accessed via the [`setPlaceholderReplacement(value)`](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/api/javadoc/org/flywaydb/core/Flyway.html#setPlaceholderReplacement-boolean-) and [`isPlaceholderReplacement()`](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/api/javadoc/org/flywaydb/core/Flyway.html#isPlaceholderReplacement--) methods of a `Flyway` object.

I know 2.2 probably didn't have that option and the accepted answer was probably the best way to solve it, but I decided this alternative could be useful to users of newer versions bumping into this page.