# How do I escape a Freemarker template in an insert statement run by a Flyway migration?

Tags: spring-boot, freemarker, flyway

I have a Spring Boot app that allows the user to define a Freemarker template.  I store that in my database.  I want to preload one as part of a migration in Flyway:

`insert into templates(1001, '${foo.bar}');`

When I put that in my migration script, I get an error about it being an unrecognized placeholder.

> org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to parse statement in /projects/so-example/src/main/resources/db/migration/V1__insert_initial_data.sql at line 1 col 1. See https://flywaydb.org/documentation/knownparserlimitations for more information: No value provided for placeholder: ${foo.bar}.  Check your configuration!

I know how to disable placeholders (`-Dflyway.placeholderReplacement=false`) and that seems to get me past it for now.

However, I'd like to know how to escape this particular instance so I could use placeholders elsewhere.

Thanks!

Comment: Some possible solutions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22045108/how-to-ignore-placeholder-expressions-for-flyway

Comment: That `'$' || '{foo.bar}'` hack is beautiful!  Thanks.  I don't know how my searches didn't land me on that question.